# Using subfigure to align images horizontally

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

Despite trying many of the suggestions I've found online, I still cannot get my figures to be aligned horizontally. For some reason, they are continually forced into a vertical alignment. I have also tried using minipage instead of subfigure. What is going on?

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{./imgs/000_test_image}        
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{./imgs/050_test_image}        
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{./imgs/100_test_image}        
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{./imgs/150_test_image}        
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{./imgs/200_test_image}        
    \end{subfigure}

    \caption{TODO}
    \label{fig:interpolated-input}
\end{figure}
```

This is my image output.
[image: This is my output]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try `\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.18\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}\end{subfigure}\hfill\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.18\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image} \end{subfigure} etc,`  and **NO** blank lines after `\hfill`.

Comment: As often as this comes up, we should make a FAQ about not putting blank lines between subfigures (unless you want a new row).  Anyway the related questions on the ;right will do for a duplicate.

Comment: Oh gosh. I see. I was interpreting people saying "don't put a new line" as saying "don't use the \newline latex command". I didn't realize that literally blank new lines would result in a new row. Thanks for clarifying....

Comment: Actually, a blank line is equivalent to `\par` (new paragraph).  Somewhat related, `\caption` begins and ends with `\par`.